# FPGA Connections

Tags: fpga, data

Im a senior EE major whose going into their senior design project. In the past Ive always struggled with data and computer systems. But as luck would have it that's what my senior design project is. One of the big questions I have is understanding the Hardware side of take the data from a global shutter camera and send that to a FPGA Board.

Honestly could even be wrong with the process but in need of some guidance to find useful material.

Thank y'all

edit
we will have to take data from a black/white python 2000 imager and transfer that data to [pico-zed-7030](http://zedboard.org/product/picozed)

[PYTHON 5.0/2.0 MegaPixels Global Shutter CMOS Image Sensors](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NOIP1SN5000A-D.PDF) I think is the product that our professor is making us use.

Comment: Please write a lot more. That is, if you know what your project is. If all you know is what you've presented here, you need to spend a lot more time refining it to something far far more concrete before presenting questions here. I don't think many of us will take an abstract and make your decisions for you about what your senior design project should be, suggest avenues of research and study for you, etc. In short, you write much too little and I think we need more than that. We know what you want to connect -- a shutter camera and an FPGA board. Don't know the board, ports on the board, etc.

Comment: This is a very open ended question.  Can you narrow it down a bit?

Comment: That's a complex sensor with multiple lanes of LVDS outputs. It's going to require getting down and dirty with the SERDES interfaces on your FPGA. It's the sort of thing that I do as a professional consultant -- it seems like rather a dive into the deep end of the pool for a senior design project!

Comment: You will have to learn why they use track/gnd width/gap ratios to control impedance, such as with Saturn PCB design.exe  then why layout is critical with every example you can find and use of each component such as SMD CM chokes and trace skew length.  every mm counts as 0.5 to 1 nH and 1mm can be several pF which you know affects impedance at 1GHz greatly. The chip looks like fun. reverse engineer the evaluation board until you fully understand it or similar ones.

Comment: I looked for a zedboard reference design for Python 2000 - didn’t find one. There is one for Python 1300. Why not contact On Semi - they might have something.

Comment: Aince they be hard to find and expensive, you will need to understand all the documents here

Comment: The one thing an engineering education needs to provide is a strategy for dividing projects into specific, individually solvable problems.  Not knowing about the particular technologies is fine; you'll be learning about new ones on a need driven basis continually.  But not knowing how how to start a project implies an education that hasn't meaningfully prepared the student.  You won't find solutions, until you start researching the right questions.